# How to take Openoffice calc excel connection to sql server instead of oledb excel connection in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, openoffice-calc

In my web application i need to import OpenOffice calc data into SQL server database i searched in google but i didn't get i found one ole-db connection instead of that how can i take open office calc data connection.

This is the ole-db connection:

```
 string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path);
```

and how can i get open office calc to connection.

Updated Code:

```
   using System.Text;
    using unoidl.com.sun.star.uno;
    using unoidl.com.sun.star.lang;
    using unoidl.com.sun.star.frame;
    using unoidl.com.sun.star.beans;
    using unoidl.com.sun.star.sheet;
    using unoidl.com.sun.star.container;
    using unoidl.com.sun.star.table;
    using unoidl.com.sun.star.text;
 protected void import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      XComponentContext oStrap = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
                XMultiServiceFactory oServMan = (XMultiServiceFactory)oStrap.getServiceManager();
                XComponentLoader desktop = (XComponentLoader)oServMan.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
                string url = @"private:factory/scalc";  
                PropertyValue[] loadProps = new PropertyValue[1];
                XComponent document = desktop.loadComponentFromURL(url, "_blank", 0, loadProps);
                XSpreadsheets oSheets = ((XSpreadsheetDocument)document).getSheets();
                XIndexAccess oSheetsIA = (XIndexAccess)oSheets;
                XSpreadsheet sheet = (XSpreadsheet)oSheetsIA.getByIndex(0).Value;
                current = ((XText)sheet.getCellByPosition(0, iRow)).getString();
}
```

can anyone tell to me how can i do this

Thank you

Comment: I already mentioned in my question web application

Comment: One thing ...I donot have installed Open Office ..So Upload a sample .xls file

Comment: My sheet also .xlsx format but i don't have ms-office i need to open  .xlsx file  for i am using open office or libra office.

Comment: Share us the file so that we can try on local machine

Comment: you can create one file .xlsx format

Answer (score 0):

My best excell convertion tool is [LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel)

Just create a Model say

```
public class ExcelData
    {
        [ExcelColumn("IMEI1")]
        public String IMEI1 { get; set; }
        [ExcelColumn("IMEI2")]
        public String IMEI2 { get; set; }
        [ExcelColumn("COLOR")]
        public String COLOR { get; set; }
    }
```

and One line of code

```
   var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory();
                List<ExcelData> allListData = new List<ExcelData>();
                try
                {
                    excel = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(@"C:\Users\Mhamudul Hasan\Desktop\FulllData.xlsx");
                    allListData = (from c in excel.Worksheet<ExcelData>("Sheet1")

                                   select c).ToList();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {


                    return;
                }
List<ExcelFullData> entities = new List<ExcelFullData>();
            using (var ctx = new testEntities())
            {

                foreach (var data in allListData)
                {
                    ExcelFullData excel1 = new ExcelFullData
                    {
                        IMEI1 = data.IMEI1,
                        IMEI2 = data.IMEI2,
                        Color = data.COLOR
                    };
                    //entities.Add(excel1);
                    ctx.ExcelFullDatas.Add(excel1);

                }
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
```

where **ExcelFullData** is database entity
Just show the file location of excel in webServer ...not sure about `Openoffice` give it a try :)

Comment: Thank you for responding, is it only oledb connection instead of connection i need to write again all the import to sql server connections can you please tell me

Comment: I also tried oledb connection in my several project ..but unknown reason ..it did not work every time ...so i gave a alternative way

Comment: i tried to insert your code but i am getting errors on ExcelQueryFactory(), <ExcelData> and LinqToExcel. how can i do this in my system i don't have ms-office i have only Open Office and Libra Office and my sheets are in .xlsx or .xls format can you please help me.Thank you

Comment: No need ...Just Install nuget package  https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToExcel/ ..and i will work

Comment: Without ms-office is it work fine when i am using oledb connection

Comment: Can you give us the OpenOffice File sample ..so that i try on my local machine

Comment: i have nuget packages

Comment: can you see my updated code i have that much only. my requirment is i need to import Open Office or Libra Office excel sheet into sql server in web application. thank you

Comment: when i trying to install linqToexcel i get this error  `Install-Package : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package LinqToExcel
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand`
 can you provide me how to do this.Thank for your responding

Comment: Install-Package LinqToExcel_x64

Comment: Thank you for your installation guides successfully added to my application. Hi are you there?

Comment: hmmmm...how can i help ??

Comment: i took your code(It is instead of olebd connections your saying) and i follow `http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/09/import-data-from-excel-to-sql-database.html` this link in this i will write oledb connection intead of your code  next i am thinking i need to provide sql connections to that is it possible or not can you say me please it is very urgent requirment thank you

Comment: Hi, i am using LinqToExcel code not oledb code i am asking that also. i am using LinqToExcel your code instead of oledb connection is it work or not i am asking. i need to add data base connection to your LinqToExcel code

Comment: my knowledge about  LinqToExcel code that it does not have sql connection....use linq objects to query database.

Comment: Without mentioned data connections is it work just now your added code `ExcelFulldata`

Answer (score 0):

For oledb

```
           //Read excell
            string input_Excell_fileName = @"Your Path";
            var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + input_Excell_fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""; ;
            DataSet ds;
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] ";

                    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
```

and database connection

```
    string WSMSconnectionstring = @"Data Source=MHAMUDUL\WALTON;Initial Catalog=WSMS;Integrated Security=True";
//Or
   // string WSMSconnectionstring = @"Data Source=MHAMUDUL\WALTON;Initial Catalog=WSMS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ssssss";
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WSMSconnectionstring))
                         {
                            con.Open();
                            string query1 = String.Format(@" Select * from ServiceTimeLog where ServiceID={0} and QCReleaseStatus is  null
     ", ServiceID);
                            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
                            SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                reader.Dispose();
                                //Update
                                string update = String.Format(@" update  ServiceTimeLog set ServiceDate=GETDATE(), StartTime=GETDATE(),EndTime=GETDATE(),QCStartTime=GETDATE(),QCEndTime=GETDATE(),QCReleaseStatus='QCPassed',ReleaseStatus='SendToQC',TechnicianID=(select UserID from Users where UserName='{0}'),QCID=(select UserID from Users where UserName='{1}') where ServiceID={2}", TechnicainID, QCID, ServiceID);
                                SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(update, con);
                                updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                reader.Dispose();
                                //Insert
                                string insert = String.Format(@"insert into ServiceTimeLog(ServiceID,ReleaseStatus,ServiceDate,StartTime,EndTime,QCStartTime,QCEndTime,QCReleaseStatus,TechnicianID,QCID)  values({0},'SendToQC',GETDATE(),GETDATE(),GETDATE(),GETDATE(),GETDATE(),'QCPassed',(select UserID from Users where UserName='{1}'),(select UserID from Users where UserName='{2}'))", ServiceID, TechnicainID, QCID);
                                SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
                                insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            cmd1.Dispose();
                            reader.Dispose();
                        }
```